# perl split an array to multiple arrays

Tags: regex, perl, split

Can someone help me with the correct use of the split function in perl

Here is my  input list called @input_lines:

```
google.com/test
yahoo.com/test
##############
somethingelse.com/test
##############
12345

my(@first_array,@second_array,@rand_no) = split(/^\#+/, @input_lines);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If format of your @input_lines strings is the same, you can similar join all strings and then split it by parts. You should notice that use split `/^#+/` is wrong in your case.

```
my $line = join ',', @input_lines;
my ($first_part, $second_part, $third_part) = split /\#+/, $line;

my @first_array  = split ',', $first_part;
my @second_array = split ',', $second_part;
my @third_array  = split ',', $third_part;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. All the others were correct too. You were the first to answer so picking yours.

Answer (score 2):

**I'll make a guess** on what you really mean:

At first, you have probably a text input file `input.txt` w/following content:

```
 google.com/test
 yahoo.com/test
 ##############
 somethingelse.com/test
 ##############
 12345
```

Now, you are trying to separate *records* from the file, delimited by 14 '#'s. Therefore, you could just read the file with `##############` as the `input record separator` and be done:

```
 ...
 my $fn = 'input.txt';             # set the file name
 open my $fh, '<', $fn or die $!;  # open the file
 $/="\n##############\n";          # set the input record separator
 my @parts = <$fh>;                # read the file record-wise
 chomp @parts;                     # remove the record separator from data
 close $fh                         # close the file
 ...
```

The elements of `@parts` now have the following content:

```
 $parts[0]
     google.com/test
     yahoo.com/test

 $parts[1]
     somethingelse.com/test

 $parts[2]
     12345
```

If you need to look for `#`-separators of different size, you might achieve this in a very similar way by *slurping* the file in one read operation and splitting at the separators afterwards:

```
 ...
 my $fn = 'input.txt';
 open my $fh, '<', $fn or die $!;
 undef $/;                           # remove the input record separator
 my @parts = split /\n#+\n/, <$fh>;  # read file as a block and split 
 close $fh;
 ...
```

with the same result.

Regards

rbo

Comment: I like the way you used `$/` to slurp the file.

Answer (score 1):

`split` operates on strings, not arrays. Also, you cannot assign to several arrays in the same assignment: the list on the right hand side gets flattened, so the first array takes all.

**Update:** This code works, though:

```
my (@first, @second, @rand);

for my $array (\@first, \@second, \@rand) {
    my $line;
    do {
        push @$array, $line = shift @input_lines
    } until $line =~ /^#+/ or ! @input_lines;
    pop @$array if @input_lines;                 # Remove the separators
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. There's an array ref each element of `$output` that represents one of your arrays.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @input_lines = (
  'google.com/test',
  'yahoo.com/test',
  '##############',
  'somethingelse.com/test',
  '##############',
  '12345',
);

my $output = []; # array ref
my $rand_no;
my $i = 0;
foreach my $line (@input_lines) {
  if ($line =~ m/^#+$/) {
    # if it's the # we move to the next index
    $i++;
    next;
  } 
  elsif ($line =~ m/^\d+$/) {
    # this is the random numer
    $rand_no = $line;
  } else {
    # everything else goes into the current index
    push @{ $output->[$i] }, $line;
  }
} 

print Dumper $output, $rand_no;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'google.com/test',
            'yahoo.com/test'
          ],
          [
            'somethingelse.com/test'
          ]
        ];
$VAR2 = '12345';
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input lines are in `$string` (otherwise use `join "\n", @input_lines`), you can use `split` like this:

```
($first, $second, $rand_no) = split /\n#+\n/m, $string;

print "`", $_, "`\n" for (@fields)'
```

Answer (score 1):

#### See both scripts below - one of them should work for you...

*Script:*

```
my @input_lines = <main::DATA>;
my $input_string = join /\n/, @input_lines; 
my @split_lines = split(/\s*[#\n\r]+\s*/, $input_string);
print "$_\n" for @split_lines;

__DATA__
google.com/test 
yahoo.com/test 
############## 
somethingelse.com/test 
############## 
12345
```

*Output:*

```
google.com/test
yahoo.com/test
somethingelse.com/test
12345
```

*See and test the code [here](http://ideone.com/TyEdr).*

---

*Script:*

```
 use Data::Dumper;

 my @input_lines = <main::DATA>;
 my $input_string = join /\n/, @input_lines; 
 my @blocks = split(/\s*#+\s*/, $input_string);
 my @matches = ();
 push @matches, [ split(/\s*[\n\r]+\s*/, $_) ] for @blocks;

 print Dumper(@matches);

 __DATA__
 google.com/test 
 yahoo.com/test 
 ############## 
 somethingelse.com/test 
 ############## 
 12345
```

*Output:*

```
 $VAR1 = [
           'google.com/test',
           'yahoo.com/test '
         ];
 $VAR2 = [
           'somethingelse.com/test '
         ];
 $VAR3 = [
           '12345'
         ];
```

*See and test the code [here](http://ideone.com/TBUm9).*